# Need to store a double with a date. I'm thinking array but am Unsure

Tags: java, arrays, transactions, calendar

I need a little logic help as well as some code help.

I'm writing a program that is suppose to be a simple ATM program.
It will do deposits
Withdrawals
And a balance check.

I also have to have my program record the date of every deposit, and use that date when calculating 5% interest over a year for when the user checks their balance. The part im having problems with is the part where I need to store the deposit amount as well as the date that corresponds to that deposit. I'm supposed to use the GregorianCalender methods.  Im just taking a shot in the dark but I think I would use an array for this. But im clueless as to how to implement it. Because I'm new to arrays.

Just to give u an idea. I have my Main class. A menu class, and a transaction class.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a `Deposit` class that contains both the deposit amount as well as the deposit date?

Comment: I don't see how you would use an array. I would add 5% interest each year. No array required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A deposit class that has an amount and a date.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Deposit {
    Double amount;
    Date depositDate;
}
```

Comment: @user2733862, As a side note, why do you calculate interest for each deposit? Interest is usual calculated periodically using the account balance.

Comment: I thought that but if one amount is deposited in june and the other in july wouldnt both those amounts have accrued different interest?

Comment: a) a `double` instead of a `Double` b) not a `double` since money does not like floating point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency :)

Comment: @zapl I agree, floating point is not good for currency, I prefer a "Money" class that is built on top of BigInteger however this *example* was built to work with the types mentioned in question. I usually default to using the object Double over the primitive double, why would you suggest using the primitive?

Comment: @user2733862 possibly, it depends on how often the interest is calculated. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest

Comment: @MikeRylander because of a) the Object creation overhead of `Double`, `double` needs no garbage collection, less memory, is quicker overall b) `Double` can be `null`, simpler / safer code if that's not possible c) error prone in case you do things like `new Double(5) == new Double(5)`. And as long as it's not a real world ATM software I'd use `double` as well.